# Copy Database Structure From MS SQL 2005 to MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2005, migration

I want to Replicate a database without data (Only the structure) with stored procedures from MS Sql Server 2005 to My SQL 5.1. Is there an easy way of doing this.

I have Installed the MySQL Workbench 5.2

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can right click on a database and go to Tasks->Generate Scripts...
Then you can basically go through generating the SQL queries that will work in MySQL

My first thought would be to not include any indexes, constraints or foreign key stuff in the queries, as MySQL handles these quite differently to SQL Server.

Just practice a few times and note down what causes errors when you use the queries in MySQL.

Using the knowledge of how MySQL handles your database objects you can try and create stored procedures that generate the queries that will create these objects on MySQL and then execute them against the MySQL database.

**EDIT :**
Ok so you want to move stored procedures over from SQL Server to MySQL. This is a fairly tricky thing to do if the stored procs are complicated.
Here is the basic overview I suggest you read before asking more specific questions about your problems.
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html
My advice is you read this and then try and migrate your stored procs and if you get errors, come back and ask specific questions about them.

Comment: Ohh,, I think i have asked the question incorrectly. What i actually meant was, i want to copy a database structure which had many tables and many stored procedures. I didnot want to do it with stored procedure, i want the stored procedure also to be copied.

I wanted to replicate the same database in MySql.

Comment: the generate scripts will still work as that will enable you to script out what you want to port across to MYSQL. You will need to perform extensive testing to make sure everything works as i expect you will find some SQL that uses T-SQL syntax rather then the ANSI standard

Comment: I found one Tool when i installed the the GUI tools for MySQL and MySQL workbench named "MySQL Migration Tool". Using this i migrated the Database with tables,, But the stored procedures are not migrated. At the moment i am converting stored procedures one by One. I will get back if there are any issues while converting.

Comment: In many of my stored procedures i use "**`SELECT Top(@RecordCount) * FROM TABLE`**" where @RecordCount is a Parameter. When i converted this sp into MySQL routine it gives an error. I am not able to pass @RecordCount with the LIMIT statement. Any way of achieving this. Thanks in Advance...